# android Unselect onscreen Keyboard on dpad navigation (blur focus)

Tags: android, android-input-method, amazon-fire-tv, d-pad

I have a keyboard on the screen (As a component inside LinearLayout. So it's always on the screen.)
I'm developing the app on an Amazon FireTV so I made an onscreen keyboard where I can use DPAD for navigation.
It all works great except the highlight seems to persist even when I'm not focusing on the keyboard.

```
import android.inputmethodservice.Keyboard;
import android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView;

private KeyboardView mKeyboardView;
private Keyboard mKeyboard;

mKeyboard = new Keyboard(getActivity(), R.xml.search_keyboard);
mKeyboardView = (KeyboardView) view.findViewById(R.id.keyboard);
mKeyboardView.setKeyboard(mKeyboard);
```

Below the keyboard is a focusable view. When I select the new view, I expect the key highlight on the keyboard to go away. But that's not happening. (If I was selecting K, K would be highlighted in yellow (This is expected) but when I navigate away from the keyboard, the highlight will stay as if the keyboard is still focused.

Any insights will be much appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: How did you get the highlight working on the on screen keyboard? I mean the dpad keys should move focus from one key to another, how did you manage that?

Comment: @RonakKhandelwal I'm gonna be honest with you I don't remember anymore. But I'm pretty sure it just worked like that out of the box. I didn't do anything extra to get it to do that.

Comment: is your keyboard open source? If yes I'd be grateful if you could allow me to have a look at that I'm facing some issues handling the dpad keys